# Is there a way to take a fixed date and change it into a date table in Lua without specifically assigning each value?

Tags: datetime, lua, formatting

I have a date which is being fed into my script in the following format:

```
dateTime = "Fri Oct 18 10:08:02 UTC 2019"
```

**Is there a way to reformat this so that I can quickly call each element as I like without explicitly splitting out using string.sub (for example)?**

E.g. So that I can:

- Subtract one date from another to find out age (using current time and birth/established date)
- Add hours dependant on the timezone (given that I have a timezone in the format "+3")
- Find if the time was between a range (e.g. the request was sent between 9am and 5pm GMT)

Comment: `Is there a way to reformat this` - Yes, but you have to write such "reformatter" function yourself.  It would take about 10 lines of code in Lua.

Comment: @Egor, that answers my question then. No inbuilt way to format incoming timestamps. Happy to accept if you add this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lua does not have a built-in date or time type like other languages.

[Lua 5.3 Reference Manual 2.1 Values and Types](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.1)

> There are eight basic types in Lua: nil, boolean, number, string,
>   function, userdata, thread, and table.

[Lua 5.3 Reference Manual 6 Standard Libraries](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6)

Either implement them yourself or find existing modules that suit your needs.

A simple way would be to parse your date time string using [captures](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4.1)

Checkout http://lua-users.org/wiki/DateAndTime for suggestions.